# Disable clickable div until function is executed.

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on animated menu using Jquery for animation sequences. And I'm trying to make it wait until animation stops in order to start the next one. 
So let's say if you click one button it starts bringing up animated elements and you can't click another buttons until everything in the function is completed. So I tried using .css('pointer-events','none') and .css('pointer-events','auto') in the beginning and the end of function, but it doesn't seem to be working. Buttons are still clickable. Is there any other way to prevent clickable div element from being clicked on, while animation is running?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            //menu buttons start animations
            $('#topstickpart').delay(300).show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 700);
            $('#topstickpart').effect( "bounce",{distance:6}, {times:3}, 600 );
            $('#bottomstickpart').delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 700);
            $('#bottomstickpart').effect( "bounce",{distance:6}, {times:3}, 600 );
            $('#biobutton').delay(300).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 700);
            $('#biobutton').effect( "bounce",{distance:6}, {times:3}, 600 );
            $('#contactbutton').delay(500).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 700);
            $('#contactbutton').effect( "bounce",{distance:6}, {times:3}, 600 );
            $('#portfoliobutton').delay(200).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 700);
            $('#resumebutton').delay(600).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 700);
            $('#screeners').delay(20).show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 700);
            $('#biowindow').hide();
            $('#screeners').effect( "bounce",{distance:1}, {times:0}, 10 );     
$('#biobutton, #resumebutton, #resumebutton,#contactbutton').css('pointer-events','none');
            $('.mainpanel').delay(50).animate({width:"660px"}, function(){
                $('.screencontainer').delay(10).animate({height:"236px"},function(){
                    $('#biowindow').fadeIn(function(){
                        $('#biobutton, #resumebutton, #resumebutton,#contactbutton').css('pointer-events','auto');
                    });
                });
            });




//onclick functionality
$('#biobutton').click(function(){
    $('#biobutton, #resumebutton, #resumebutton,#contactbutton').css('pointer-events','none');
    $('#biowindow, #resumewindow, #contactwindow, #dworkswindow').hide(function(){
        $('.mainpanel').animate({width:"100px"}, function(){
            $('.screencontainer').animate({height:"100px"}, 100, function(){
                $('#screeners').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 300, function(){
                    $('.topscreen').animate({top:"-105px"});
                    $('#screeners').show("slide", { direction: "up"}, 300, function(){                          
                            $('.mainpanel').animate({width:"660px", paddingTop:"300px"}, function(){
                                $('.screencontainer').delay(10).animate({height:"236px"}, 300, function(){
                                    $('#biowindow').fadeIn(function(){
                                        $('#biobutton, #resumebutton, #resumebutton,#contactbutton').css('pointer-events','auto');
                                    });
                                });                     
                            });


                    });
                });

            });     
        });


    });
    $('#toppanelslide').slideUp(300,'swing');

});




$('#resumebutton').click(function(){

    $('#biobutton, #resumebutton, #resumebutton,#contactbutton').css('pointer-events','none');
    $('#biowindow, #resumewindow, #contactwindow, #dworkswindow').hide(function(){
        $('.mainpanel').animate({width:"100px"}, function(){
            $('.screencontainer').animate({height:"100px"}, 100, function(){
                $('#screeners').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 300, function(){
                    $('.topscreen').animate({top:"-315px"});    
                    $('#screeners').show("slide", { direction: "up"}, 300, function(){                                              
                            $('.mainpanel').animate({width:"800px", paddingTop:"100px"}, function(){
                                $('.screencontainer').delay(10).animate({height:"720px"},function(){
                                    $('#resumewindow').fadeIn(function(){
                                        $('#biobutton, #resumebutton, #resumebutton,#contactbutton').css('pointer-events','auto');
                                    });
                                });                     
                            });


                    });
                });

            });     
        });


    });
    $('#toppanelslide').slideUp(300,'swing');

});



$('#portfoliobutton').click(function(){
    $('#biobutton, #resumebutton, #resumebutton,#contactbutton').css('pointer-events','none');
    $('#biowindow, #resumewindow, #contactwindow, #dworkswindow').hide(function(){
        $('.mainpanel').animate({width:"100px"}, function(){
            $('.screencontainer').animate({height:"100px"}, 100, function(){
                $('#screeners').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 300, function(){
                    $('.topscreen').animate({top:"-105px"});
                    $('#screeners').show("slide", { direction: "up"}, 300, function(){                          
                            $('.mainpanel').animate({width:"800px", paddingTop:"300px"}, function(){
                                $('.screencontainer').delay(10).animate({height:"340px"},function(){
                                    $('#dworkswindow').fadeIn(function(){
                                        $('#biobutton, #resumebutton, #resumebutton,#contactbutton').css('pointer-events','auto');
                                    });
                                });                     
                            });


                    });
                });

            });     
        });


    });
    $('#toppanelslide').slideDown(300,'swing');

});



$('#contactbutton').click(function(){
    $('#biobutton, #resumebutton, #resumebutton,#contactbutton').css('pointer-events','none');
    $('#biowindow, #resumewindow, #contactwindow, #dworkswindow').hide(function(){
        $('.mainpanel').animate({width:"100px"}, function(){
            $('.screencontainer').animate({height:"100px"}, 100, function(){
                $('#screeners').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 300, function(){
                    $('.topscreen').animate({top:"-105px"});
                    $('#screeners').show("slide", { direction: "up"}, 300, function(){                          
                            $('.mainpanel').animate({width:"660px", paddingTop:"300px"}, function(){
                                $('.screencontainer').delay(10).animate({height:"250px"},function(){
                                    $('#contactwindow').fadeIn(function(){
                                        $('#biobutton, #resumebutton, #resumebutton,#contactbutton').css('pointer-events','auto');
                                    });
                                });                     
                            });


                    });
                });

            });     
        });


    });
    $('#toppanelslide').slideUp(300,'swing');

});





});
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?, create stacksnippets , jsfiddle jttp://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: I suggest reading [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Comment: I would be seriously concerned with the performance of so much nested "oncomplete" callback functionality.

Comment: There is no other way I can create that animation, only using a long series of jquery animations. I need a panel to slide in on clicked button, frame elements change their proportions and inside content to fade in. And all of that repeated backwards on clicking another button. A problem is that once you click another button before the function is completed it all goes crazy. I need to either reset all animations on click or disable clickability until it's finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.is()` , `:animated` selector , `.off()` .

```js
var elems = $("div");
// only one `div` element at a time should be animated,
// on `click` event of any `div` element 
// if `this` is not currently animated , or another `div` currently animated
function fx() {
  console.log($(this).is(":animated"));
  // if `this` is not currently animated, do stuff
  // remove `click` event from `elems`,
  // call `.animate()` on `$(this)` jQuery object
  !$(this).is(":animated") && elems.off("click", fx) && $(this).animate({
    fontSize: "+=20"
  }, 2000, function() {
    // when animation complete re-attach `click` event to `elems`
    elems.click(fx)

  })
}

elems.click(fx)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>click 1</div>
<div>click 2</div>
<div>click 3</div>
```

Comment: I basically need all other buttons disabled while function is being executed. In your example you can still click all of them while function is running.

Comment: @NebularDust _"need all other buttons disabled while function is being executed."_ See updated post , defined `click` handler as named function ,  added `.off()`

Comment: I'll try to wrap my head around it, but it looks like what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I would suggest you to prevent the default behaviour on click

```
jQuery('body').on('click', 'button.selector', function(e){ 
e.preventDefault();
})
```

and when it's done you can make the opposite

```
jQuery('body').on('click', 'button.selector', function(e){ 
return true;
})
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hm, doesn't seem to be working. I tried writing it as $('body').on('click', '#biobutton, #resumebutton, #resumebutton,#contactbutton', function(e){ 
return true;
});